# OpenLayers: Remove clusters on certain zoomlevel (even for same coordinates)

Tags: gis, openlayers, openlayers-7

I am using OpenLayers 7 and I have a dataset which contains a lot of geojson features which I need to mark on the map. To get an okayish performance I need to cluster them when zoomed out. This works all alright, but the problem is that the dataset contains a lot of data points which have the exact same coordinates.

This results in markers that will never be unclustered. Because the need to be clickable and show a specific icon I wanted to come up with this quick fix:

Whenever the zoomlevel is above a certain amount I would like not to cluster at all any more and show the icons instead. If they are on top of each other I wouldn't care for now.

I tried different ways, for example setting the distance `source.setDistance(0)` but this does not work, because markers that are at the same point will be clustered even if the distance is set to 0.

I have this code for the clusterSource:

```js
this.clusterLayer = new VectorLayer({
   source: this.clusterSource,
   style: this.clusterStyle,
})
// ...
function clusterStyle(feature) {
  const size = feature.get('features')?.length
  let style = this.styleCache[size]
  const fastLoadingIcon = new Icon({
    src: FastLoadingIcon,
    anchor: [0.5, 1], // bottom center
    scale: 0.75,
  })
  const loadingIcon = new Icon({
    src: LoadingIcon,
    anchor: [0.5, 1], // bottom center
    scale: 0.75,
  })
  if (!style) {
    if (size === 1) {
      return new Style({
        image:
          feature.get('features')[0].get('PowerMap')['75-100kW'] ||
          feature.get('features')[0].get('PowerMap')['100+kW']
            ? fastLoadingIcon
            : loadingIcon,
      })
    }
    style = new Style({
      image: new CircleStyle({
        radius: 11,
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: '#fff',
        }),
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#21387D',
        }),
      }),
      text: new Text({
        text: size.toString(),
        fill: new Fill({
          color: '#fff',
        }),
      }),
    })
    this.styleCache[size] = style
  }
  return style
},
```

I don't fully understand what's going on, but I copied together code from OpenLayers examples, for example from here:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/clusters-dynamic.html

The part where
`if (size === 1) {..` I can define that I show an icon instead of the cluster.

What I would like to achieve now is that clusters are resolved after a certain zoom level OR I could also imagine that I just show the cluster in another style, showing an icon instead of a circle with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your would need separate clustered and unclustered layers.

You could control visibility via `minZoom` and `maxZoom` options

```
clusterSource = new ClusterSource({
  source: source,
});
layer = new VectorLayer({
  source: source,
  minZoom: limit,
});
clusterLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: clusterSource,
  maxZoom: limit,
});
```

or by checking resolution in the style functions, e.g.

```
function(feature, resolution) {
  if (resolution < map.getView().getResolutionForZoom(limit)) {
    return;
  }
  return style;
}
```